# Django if statement not working

Tags: python, django, object, if-statement

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}

<h1>{{ page }}</h1>

{% for category in categories %}
    {% if category.page == page %}
        <h2>{{ category.title }}!</h2>

    {% for item in categoryitems %}
        {{ category.title }} {{ item.category }}
        {% if item.category == category.title %}
            <h3>{{ item.title }}</h3>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

The first statement `if category.page == page` is working fine, but the other one - `if item.category == category.title` - doesn't, for the sake of checking if everything is fine I've also added those `{{category.title}}` and `{{item.category}}` outputs and they are identical, so why doesn't the loop show me my `item.title` ? Without the `if`, it works, but, of course, shows every element in the list, which is smthn I don't need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not depend on the page output to tell you what is correct, since the output is dependent on the code. Instead, do it correctly in the first place.

```
    {% if item.category == category %}
```